# Loop the posts between two dates selected using jquery datepicker

Tags: wp-query, filters, jquery, datepicker

I went through [this link](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-loop-get-posts-published-between-two-particular-dates) where we can restrict the loop to display the posts  only between two dates and it works fine. But if I have a Jquery Datepicker with `from` and `to` date, then how can I pass that selected date inside the where clause? For example,

```
<?php
  function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= 'FromDate' AND post_date <= 'ToDate'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
?>
```

Where `FromDate` and `ToDate` are the selected values of jquery datepicker.

Comment: You could load the posts via ajax. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Date parameters in WP_Query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters. You can pick up the values using a form submit or Ajax.